# visual studio 2012 says expected selector for style rule for a new C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, text

I have VS2005, VS2008, VS2010, VS2012 in my system.

This is a strange issue what i have been seeing since a few days.

This is happening with any project i open in VS2012

Intellisense DOES Not work

C# Text editor shows errors in my cs files.

-> Expected selector for style rule.

-> Block is unclosed '}' expected

Please see the screen shot.

However if i build the project there are no build errors.

Please let me know how can i correct the C# Text editor

```
      class Program // class is shown in red
{
    static void Main(string[] args) // every space is shown in red if i however on anu space the tool tip says Missing colon between property and value.
    {
    }

}
    With name spaces i get following error
    using System; // Expected selector for style rule
```

This is only happening with VS2012.
If i open same project in VS2010 everything is fine.

Comment: just reinstall vs2012

Answer (score 0):

It was because i had installed resharper 5.0 which is not supported for VS2012
Hence VS2012 does used to show such an error. It used to compile though
I used reshaprer 8.0 and things are sorted out now

Comment: This isn't the reason. I don't have resharper installed and i still have the same problem. Ohh and i'm using VS2013.